# Making things stand out in Jquery Dialog Overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overlay, modal-dialog

I have a requirement to achieve a close button as seen in this picture:

[image]

But in practice I am able to achieve only this:

[image]

I did it with following CSS style. I can't have the `position:absolute` since the location of the dialog may change.

```
margin-right:-10px;
margin-top:-10px;
```

Any Ideas guys on how could I achieve this?

Comment: @sandeep the css code that I have applied to that image is given in my answer. and I am using jquery UI Dialog to display this.

Comment: May be there is an overflow:hidden in your overlay div. Os, remove it

Comment: @sandeep the div of dialog or background-overlay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use z-index and positioning. The simplest way to do this is to have the close button div outside the dialog div and set the z-index of the dialog to a lower number than close button

This web can be useful to you http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp

**UPDATED** http://jsfiddle.net/vj9Wb/

```
<div class="window-container">
    <div class="window-close">X</div>
    <div class="window-content">window content</div>
</div>

<style>
    .window-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #EEE;
    }

    .window-close {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: #AAA;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    .window-content {
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        background: #AAF;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        z-index: 9998;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: As already mentioned in the answer, Z-Indexes don't seem to work.

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements (absolute, relative or fixed)

Comment: Yes, I tried it with relative, it did hides it, but doesn't comes above overlay.

Comment: I know about normal divs, was just looking for solutions where one can show that corner button on a jquery-ui-dialog

Comment: perhaps a jsfiddle or an online version will help